# How to identify CSS or xpath and convert html tables into dataframes?

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

Hi I'm trying to scrape https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges/binance using Rselenium and Rvest. I'm really interested in this project even though I only have small knowledge in coding. Hoping someone will lead me to the right direction.

I was able to make it work using rvest with a different code but I'm being limited with 50 data only because I can't find a workaround on the *"show more"* button.

--Here's the process flow (After navigating to the website)

1.) By using **loop** It will click the ***"show more*****"** button on the first table until there's no more left.

2.) Extract the data on the table.

3.) Convert html table into Data frame

4.) Save to CSV

*Challenges

1.) I can't make the loop work. I think I'm using the wrong class/xpath (confused how to identify.)

2.) I want to extract the first column but can't figure out what class/xpath I should put in the code.

3.) I was able to turn html to datasets using rvest, xml2 (stored url) but now I have no idea how to make it work with Rselenium. Any link to tutorials will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

driver <- remoteDriver()
driver$open()


driver$navigate("https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges/binance")



ShowMore ({
    Sys.sleep(5)
  suppressMessages ({

      showmore_btn <- driver$findElement("Class", "btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1")
    while(showmore_btn$isElementDisplayed()[[1]]){
      showmore_btn$clickElement()
      Sys.sleep(10)
      showmore_btn <- driver$findElement("class", "btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1")
    }
  })
},
error = function(e) {
  NA_character_
})

html_data <- driver$getPageSource()[[1]]
htmldata %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(".") %>%
html_attr("href")

#converts html tables into dataframes


write.csv(html_data, "Coingecko Latest Volume")
```

Comment: Mind that they offer an API to request the data per URL: https://www.coingecko.com/en/api . If that suits your needs you won't have to simulate a web browser - unless that's your actual interest of course.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to check it out

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges/binance"


read_html(url) %>% 
  html_element(xpath = '//*[@id="markets"]/div/div[2]') %>% 
  html_table()
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 50 × 12
     `#` Coin                      `Market Cap`        Pair      Price                         Spread `+2% Depth` `-2% Depth` `24h Volume`           `Volume %` `Last Traded` `Trust Score`
   <int> <chr>                     <chr>               <chr>     <chr>                         <chr>  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>         <lgl>        
 1     1 "Bitcoin\n/\nTether"      $818,318,162,545.68 BTC/USDT  "$43,092.10\n\n43103 USDT"    0.01%  $25,515,001 $21,867,327 "$1,903,904,039\n \n4… 10.36%     Recently      NA           
 2     2 "Ethereum\n/\nTether"     $364,805,278,069.74 ETH/USDT  "$3,038.39\n\n3040.19 USDT"   0.01%  $26,850,657 $11,691,663 "$1,531,387,527\n \n5… 8.34%      Recently      NA           
 3     3 "Binance...\n/\nTether"   $17,649,975,489.72  BUSD/USDT "$1.00\n\n0.9995 USDT"        0.01%  $88,473,714 $66,661,930 "$764,952,254\n \n765… 4.16%      Recently      NA           
 4     4 "ApeCoin\n /\nTether"     $2,415,880,396.94   APE/USDT  "$14.34\n\n14.3415 USDT"      0.03%  $3,666,651  $3,492,905  "$592,369,004\n \n413… 3.22%      Recently      NA           
 5     5 "Bitcoin\n/\nBinance..."  $818,318,162,545.68 BTC/BUSD  "$43,064.38\n\n43119.77 BUSD" 0.01%  $11,392,485 $13,300,407 "$542,515,491\n \n125… 2.95%      Recently      NA           
 6     6 "Loopring\n/\nTether"     $1,380,968,843.56   LRC/USDT  "$1.10\n\n1.1052 USDT"        0.02%  $731,068    $774,477    "$483,094,499\n \n437… 2.63%      Recently      NA           
 7     7 "Cardano\n/\nTether"      $36,353,319,987.05  ADA/USDT  "$1.14\n\n1.138 USDT"         0.09%  $2,418,833  $2,506,293  "$437,868,499\n \n384… 2.39%      Recently      NA           
 8     8 "Ethereum\n/\nBinance..." $364,805,278,069.74 ETH/BUSD  "$3,044.90\n\n3045.63 BUSD"   0.01%  $5,781,558  $10,258,913 "$407,185,464\n \n133… 2.22%      Recently      NA           
 9     9 "Ethereu...\n/\nTether"   $5,907,151,680.36   ETC/USDT  "$44.03\n\n44.04 USDT"        0.02%  $791,333    $920,964    "$349,260,416\n \n793… 1.90%      Recently      NA           
10    10 "Solana\n/\nTether"       $31,369,956,754.28  SOL/USDT  "$97.23\n\n97.25 USDT"        0.01%  $3,050,523  $2,598,698  "$330,473,923\n \n339… 1.80%      Recently      NA           
# … with 40 more rows
```

you can Identify the xpath e.g. in chrome with:
go to "settings" -> "more tools" -> "developer tools" -> use the courser and go over the table. sometimes you cant't select it properly, just mouseover the code whre you believe is the table.

[image]

right click on it and select: copy as xpath